# Files from another git repo in the project root directory

Tags: git, github

I have several boiler-plate files that I would like to reuse in multiple projects.  These files (such as a Makefile, gitpod config files, or CI/CD config files) need to reside in the base directory of the project, so I can't create a subdirectory with another repo.

How do to have these files in the project, but also have a link back to a common utility project so I can pull updates to all projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest, most pain-free way to do this if possible is to use a submodule with symlinks.  That makes updating as easy as possible.  However, it may not be possible in all cases, so there are other things you can try.

You can take your boilerplate repo and merge it into your project repo with `--allow-unrelated-histories`.  If you need to pull in additional changes, you can then merge in additional changes from the boilerplate repository.

Note that this will work poorly if you already have files with the same names in your project repository, so you may want to avoid that.